# com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: Firebase ID token isn't signed by a valid public key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to verify Id Token sent by android client app on my java server using firebase admin sdk. I followed

[Admin Sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) and  [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setServiceAccount(sce.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/serviceAccountKey.json"))
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://[project-id].firebaseio.com/")
    .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
FirebaseToken decodedToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdTokenAsync(idToken).get();
    String uid = decodedToken.getUid();
```

Retrive ID token from Android client

```
mAuth.signInAnonymously()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
   @Override
   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
       if (task.isSuccessful()) {
           final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
           user.getIdToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                   String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                   Log.e(TAG,"signInAnonymously:success :  onComplete : "+token);
                   callApi(token);
               }
           });

        } else {
            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Authentication failed.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

Getting exception on server

> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: Firebase ID token
>   **isn't signed by a valid public key**. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for
>   details on how to retrieve an ID token.   at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FirebaseTokenVerifier.verifyTokenAndSignature(FirebaseTokenVerifier.java:147)
>     at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$2.call(FirebaseAuth.java:223)
>     at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$2.call(FirebaseAuth.java:211)
>     at com.google.firebase.tasks.Tasks$1.run(Tasks.java:82)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code.(Just only delete the setDatabaseUrl if you that not use.)

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
.setServiceAccount(sce.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/serviceAccountKey.json"))
.build();
```